# Update ms access not working

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-update

This update does not work when I do a `DoCmd.RunSQL` SQL in a VBA MS Access command:

```
UPDATE  T SET T.Quantità =  T.Quantità - C.SommaDiQuantità 
  FROM  [Scorta a magazzino] AS T INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Pazienti-Medicinali].[ID Medicinale], Sum([Pazienti-Medicinali].Quantità) AS SommaDiQuantità 
  FROM [Pazienti-Medicinali] GROUP BY [Pazienti-Medicinali].[ID Medicinale] )  AS C
  ON T.[ID Medicinale] = C.[ID Medicinale]
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Access doesn't let you perform an update on grouped data.

Normally you would have to break this out into two steps, first by loading the summed values into a table, then linking to this table and performing the update.

If you really wanted a workaround I think you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE [Scorta a magazzino] AS T
SET T.Quantità =  T.Quantità - Nz(DSUM("Quantità", "[Pazienti-Medicinali]", "[ID Medicinale] = " & T.[ID Medicinale]), 0)
```